# python docker apis is it possible to create a container and just run a command?

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I want to create a container and then run a command.
Is this possible using python docker apis ?

I was able to create the container but I was not sure how to run a command inside that container.. does anybody know ? if I use run , it creates another container to run the command but I wanted to run in the same container.

The below throws "cannot exec in a stopped state: unknown"

I know one way to do is using 'cat' command and keep the container running but thats not ideal.

```
def createContainer(image, cmd, **kwargs):
    container = dockerClient.containers.create(image=image, command=None,
                                               **kwargs)
    return container

def startContainer(container, **kwargs):
    container.start(**kwargs)

def runCommand(container, cmd):
    res = container.exec_run(cmd)
    print res.output
```

Comment: can't you just run/start the container and use the attach method? as in normal standalone docker

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior. If I maintain the same container object, `exec_run` does not create a new container.

Comment: the container should be running to perform exec_run.. how do you keep container running ?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you have attempted via CL?